# How to validate click one per browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, react-hooks, jsx

How can i reduce raiting to be able to rate only once per browser?

I need to make validation for raiting component in React where client can rate only once per browser.

Here is example of the rating component:

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <Box component="fieldset" mb={3} borderColor="transparent">
        <Typography component="legend">Rate</Typography>
        <Rating
          name="pristine"
          value={value}
          onClick={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is sandbox link of the component  [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-mcclintock-xnmoj?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You need to do that on the server and need something to uniquely identify the client. E.g. with either the IP address or better an unique login. This doesn't really have anything todo with react but is rather a question about the rating endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One possible solution you could think of is to use localStorage**

For every user, who has already rate, you then store a boolean to the local storage.

Then next time, it will be validated first

Something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const hasRated = localStorage.getItem("hasRated");

  const handleRate = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    localStorage.setItem("hasRated", true);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Box component="fieldset" mb={3} borderColor="transparent">
        <Typography component="legend">Rate</Typography>
        <Rating
          disabled={hasRated}
          name="pristine"
          value={value}
          onClick={handleRate}
        />
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

*Please note, that this is only a demonstrated example, so it supposes that you will need to have some improvement based on your needs*

Sanbox Example:

[image: Edit ancient-leaf-3131m]

Comment: Lol, I mean, if it pleases the client, right? :D

Comment: Yeah, He wants to make it check for every browser, not every machine or user, right?

Comment: Just as a note: This is not at all validated and with a few clicks each *"browser"* can vote as many times as it wants.